# Explanation for certain options of `SolveAlways`?

Tags: equation-solving, undocumented

As one can see,

```
In[1]:= Options[SolveAlways]

Out[1]= {InverseFunctions -> Automatic, MakeRules -> False, 
 Method -> 3, Mode -> Generic, Sort -> True, 
 WorkingPrecision -> \[Infinity]}
```

Both `InverseFunctions -> Automatic` and `WorkingPrecision -> Infinity` are well-documented; `MakeRules -> True` has been explained [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/AlgebraicRules/algdat.html#21310), `Mode -> Modular` is explained [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html?view=all#130988174), and `Sort -> True` has been explained [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html?view=all#29115). But what are the meanings of `Method -> 3` and `Mode -> Generic`?
According to `` Message[SolveAlways::method, "`1`"] ``,

> Value of option **Method** -> `1` should be *1*, *2*, or *3*.

And according to `?Mode`,

> **Mode** is an option to Solve and related functions that specifies in what sense the equations are to be solved. The possible settings for **Mode** are *Generic*, *Modular*, and *Rational*.

So, what is the difference among the three `Method` options and the three `Mode` options?

Comment: These are outdated options. Legacy from an earlier time.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. Yet is the `Mode` also out-dated? The [help page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html?view=all#130988174) does not mark it as an out-dated option. 
Besides, in `Options[SolveAlways]`, the default method is `Method -> 3`, while in `Options[Eliminate]`, the default method is `Method -> 1`; is there any difference?

Comment: Those are settings I have not touched in this millennium. Are the `Method` ones different? Probably. What do they do that's different? I don't remember. Re `Mode`, I believe `the idea was that one could use the `Generic` to get `Solve to give generic solutions ad `Reduce` give a full breakdown using the `Rational` setting (maybe). One could use `Mode->Modular` and give an extra equation, and `Solve` would try to find a modulus for which the system was noy over-determined.  My guess is this can instead be handled with an existential quantifier, in a way that might be more reliable.

Comment: I will add that I do not see delving into this legacy design as a particularly productive use of time. It's been superceded for a reason.